# Jenkinsfile not getting updated in jenkins workspace even though Git is updated

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am using Jenkins 2.73.2 with Blue ocean 1.3.1 in the Linux Redhat. I wanted to build maven project located at GitHub repository. I have created a JenkinsFile for a blue ocean pipeline and recently updated it with some changes which were saved successfully on GitHub repository. But when I am running the pipeline again it is still running the old JenkinsFile.

So I checked the workspace of Jenkins and found that the folder for that pipeline was not updated and has old JenkinsFile which is causing this issue. Now I am stuck and don't know where did I go wrong or what I have missed in configuration/settings?

Comment: BlueOcean is just the UI. Pipelines work the same also without BlueOcean.

Comment: The log says "Running on XXX in /var/lib..". Are you really checking that workspace directory? Maybe add your build output.

Comment: @StephenKing thanks for the help :)

Comment: Really sorry for the late reply. This issue got resolved when I used the option available in the jobs where we can clear the workspace before running any jobs.

Answer (score 0):

As susmit says in a comment,

> This issue got resolved when I used the option available in the jobs where we can clear the workspace before running any jobs.

to avoid this problem you can use the option "Clear Workspace before running job" available in the jobs parameters.

Comment: Isn't this an expensive choice?  If I have a large repo, should I have to clear it to ensure that one file is up-to-date?

Comment: Yup, it's a little bit overkill but in most of CI/CD software you need to use this method. I haven't used Jenkins for a while so check if there is an option to clear sources only.